# Proving something is a real inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

[image]

I have this question here that I'm trying to solve. I need to show that $S$ is equipped with an inner product and is thus an inner product space.

I've started out by trying to prove this with the axiom of symmetry, which it satisfied, but where it gets confusing for me is trying to prove it using the remaining axioms of additivity, homogeneity and positivity.

How would I go about proving $S$ is an inner product space using the remaining axioms, if that is in fact the correct way of going about it?

Comment: You really just have to plug in the definition and verify the axioms.

Comment: Yeah, that's what's confusing for me. Usually the inner product follows a pattern similar to: x1y1 + x2y2, etc. but these ones are mixed in that you have v1u1 - v1u2 - v2u1, etc. I just can't see how I can start by proving it using the axiom of additivity where (u + v, w) = (u, w) + (v, w)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to show that this is an inner product, you do indeed need to check every property from the definition. Let me show an easy way to do it: first, you can write this operation as:

$$\left<u,v\right> = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 & u_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

It now suffices to show that this matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, which is the form's associated matrix in the standard basis, is symmetric and positive definite. You can clearly see it's symmetric. For positive-definiteness, you can use [Sylvester's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion). You can check that the principal minors of the matrix are $2$ and $2 - (-1)(-1) = 1$, both positive, and hence the bilinear form is positive definite, and, with everything we've seen so far, an inner product.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm afraid that's a little outside of the scope of what we're learning. I'm trying to see how I can prove it using the axioms: (u + v, w) = (u, w) + (v, w), c (u, v) = (cu, v), etc.

Comment: Are you familiar with the properties of matrices? If so, you can easily see that, for example $(u+v,w) = (u+v)^T A w = u^TAw + v^TAw = (u,w) + (v,w)$, and so forth. If you're not familiar with this, you need to write $u = (u_1,u_2)$, $v = (v_1,v_2)$, $w = (w_1,w_2)$, plug the coordinates for $u+v$ and $w$ into the formula, and manipulate to reach the formula for $(u,w) + (v,w)$.

Comment: I managed to reach that axiom, but I instead used $w$ = ($w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$, $w_4$), since I couldn't see how I could do it with just 2, since there are four terms in the original function and couldn't see how I could just use $w_1$ and $w_2$ in the dot product. Would that also be correct?

Comment: The application $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ takes in two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence four coordinates indeed. I don't agree with your notation, though, as it seems that you're using just one vector from $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: I don't see how else I could it using just $w$ = ($w_1$, $w_2$).

Comment: I'm gonna detail it, hoping to clarify. We have $\left< u+v,w\right> = \left<(u_1+v_1,u_2+v_2),(w_1,w_2)\right>$. We now use the formula to see that this is $2(u_1+v_1)w_1 - (u_1+v_1)w_2 - (u_2+v_2)w_1 + (u_2+v_2)w_2$. Factor things to reach: $2u_1w_1-u_1w_2-u_2w_1+u_2w_2 + 2v_1w_1-v_1w_2-v_2w_1+v_2w_2 = \left<(u_1,u_2),(w_1,w_2)\right> + \left<(v_1,v_2),(w_1,w_2)\right> = \left<(u,w)\right> + \left<(v,w)\right>$.

Comment: Got you now. It helped rewording it as: ⟨(1+1,2+2),(1,2)⟩ I can see how it works now. Thank you!